# How to pass data between two controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This  is located within the search Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string what, string where, int page = 1, string cn = "", string sv = "", string ch = "", string deals = "", int brand = 0)
```

And this is my second controller named Quotaion that i want to pass values of the parameters of the above controller but i hardcoded them to search plumbers so how do i pass them dynamically from search controller to Quotation Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   WhereInfo interLoc = new WhereInfo();

    //      SearchService.ResultSet resultSet = (neSearchService.Search()).getSearchResults("plumbers", interLoc, 1.ToString(), User.Identity.Name, "iyp", "", "", "", "", "", "plumbers", 0);

    //    ViewBag.Search = resultSet;

    //    return View();
}
```

Comment: Give more details on the process. Are you redirecting the browser from SearchController to QuotationController? Or are you changing controller in the same request?

Answer (score 1):

redirect to the other controller?

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Quotation", new { what = whatParam, where = whereParam, page = pageParam, cn = cnParam, sv = svParam, ch = chParam, deals = dealsParam, brand = brandParam });
```

Alternatively, put the data into TempData[], however this storage will only be valid for the duration of the request.

Comment: It says the assigned variables are not defined in the current context,where exatly do I put this

Answer (score 0):

Try using TempData

```
 public ActionResult Index(string what, string where, int page = 1, string cn = "", string sv      = "", string ch = "", string deals = "", int brand = 0)
 {
    TempData["details"] = your_variable_with_details;
    return RedirectToAction("OtherAction");
 }
```

In your QuotationController, test if `TempData["details"]` is null.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{  
       if(TempData["details"]!=null){
           // do something here
       }
}
```

TempData is used to pass simple data without exposing the data to the client